# Shilov's Linear Algebra - Chapter 1, Problem 9

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Calculate the $n$-th order determinant:

$$\Delta=
\begin{vmatrix}
x&a&a&\ldots&a\\
a&x&a&\ldots&a\\
a&a&x&\ldots&a\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\ldots&\cdot\\
a&a&a&\ldots&x
\end{vmatrix}$$

The answer is $\Delta=[x+a(n-1)](x-a)^{n-1}$.

If we add all the other columns to the first column, we get the first multiplicative factor of the answer, and are left with the following determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&a&a&\ldots&a\\
1&x&a&\ldots&a\\
1&a&x&\ldots&a\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\ldots&\cdot\\
1&a&a&\ldots&x
\end{vmatrix}$$

How can we calculate this determinant to obtain the answer?

Comment: Hint: add the first column multiplied by $-a$ to the other columns.

Comment: Subtract the last row from all other rows. Then to the last column add all other columns.

Answer (score 3):

If the matrix $J$ is the square $n\times n$ matrix with all $1$'s as its entries, then your matrix, call it $M$, is given by $M=(x-a)I+aJ$.

The eigen values of $J$ are $n$ once and $0$, $n-1$ times, so the eigenvalues of $aJ$ are $an$ once and $0$, $n-1$ times. Therefore the eigenvalues of $(x-a)I+aJ$ are $an+x-a$ once and $x-a$, $n-1$ times.

The determinant of $M$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $M$, hence $$\Delta=[x+a(n-1)](x-a)^{n-1}$$

Comment: This question is asked every 3 months or so (see the reference I gave).

Comment: @JeanMarie are suggesting I delete my answer or...?

Comment: No don't delete it ! It was just a remark.

Comment: @JeanMarie ok, gotcha. it’s hard to pick up tone of voice over the internet sometimes

Comment: It's right that interpretation of intentions is eased when you hear the voice or, even better, see the face of people... For a future release of Maths SE...